# Banning a certain user

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-user

I suggest the instant banning of **[this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/112557/poop)** before it gets too late. Obviously, it is either a spambot or a multi.

Comment: What's a mutli?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Multiple account.

Comment: Thanks.  What's a multiple account?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Let's say you were to log out right now and make a new account on StackExchange for some weird reason which could either be trolling, an excess amount of boredom, or something else. You just made a multi.

Comment: $\text{@}$AhaanRungta: Thanks!

Comment: @JonasMeyer No problem!

Comment: multi, not mutli ;)

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Derp. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've destroyed the user.

And random characters...

Comment: Great, thanks! :)

Comment: Mad with power. I knew it was just a matter of time.

Comment: There is some disagreement as to whether it is MWAHAHAHA or BWAHAHAHA or other.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_laughter

Comment: @Will: Wait, what?! You're only just *now* noticing...

Comment: @cardinal, I was busy.